# Managed Chromebook - How identify customers ? Asset-ID ? Policy?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-workspace

I have a private extension in the chrome web store. This extension is for users and devices who are managed via the Google Admin / GSuit system.

When in use, the extension contacts the GSuit / big data servers to log data. To tell my customers appart, I get them to type in a unique customer ID into each of their chromebooks, one ID per customer.

This was ok, but I would like to automate the system. Can I send down the customer ID instead of getting them to type it in ?

I thought of using the Asset-ID to identify the chromebook - but I cant find any way to extract the asset-id in my extension to allow the device to send it back to the server !

I thought of using one of the free text policy settings - but I can't get access to those in the app either !

I don't want to use email address as some of my smaller customers use gmail, so they would all get clumped together.

Answer (score 0):

As an account administrator, you can first try [retrieving a user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user) using a `userKey` which can be the user's primary email address, the unique user id, or one of the user's alias email addresses. A successful [`Users:get`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) request will return users resource including `customerID`.

Then, with the `customerID`, you may now get the `assetID` by [retrieving all chrome devices for an account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-chrome-devices#get_all_chrome_devices). Use `GET` request and include the authorization described in [Authorize requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing).

Here's the sample request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer or customerId/
devices/chromeos?projection=basic or full&query=query
&orderBy=orderBy category&sortOrder=ascending or descending order
&pageToken=token for next results page
&maxResults=max number of results per page
```

Response for this request will include `annotatedAssetId`.

Also, [View Chrome device information](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/1698333) might also help.